# modifying ip packet using libipq

Tags: linux, network-programming, packet-sniffers, netfilter

I am using libipq to modify some data in the incoming packets in the network. Here's my setup:
I have both the client program and the sniffer (using libipq) programs running on the same machine. I have a server program on a different machine. The two machines are on network. My aim is to change certain data in certain packets that I receive from the server. I am able to successfully change the data but this changed packet doesn't seem to reach the client. I also see in wireshark that the server is re-transmitting the packet that I just modified (as it was expecting an ack for its earlier packet and as the client never received it, it is unable to send an ack). I am using the following statement to accept the packet after changing a part of it. Here, I am not changing the length of the packet. I am only replacing the data with some other data.

```
ipq_set_verdict (h, m->packet_id, NF_ACCEPT, m->data_len, m->payload);
```

I would like some advice on how I can make the modified packet reach the client.. All unmodified packets are reaching the client without any problem.

Comment: Is it a tcp packet? Did you rewrite the check sum in the replayed packet? Are you dropping the original packet using say ip tables? OR the original goes unmodified and you are merely replaying a duplicate sniffed from interface. How about sequence numbers in the pcap?

Comment: The checksum would change as long you modify ANY THING in the packet. First, verify that it is rewritten appropriately. Secondly, What about sequence number? If you are not dropping any thing, then the original packet with the same sequence number has already been received by the other end. So now you replay the same packet with different data but same sequence number. The other end should silently discard it.

Comment: It is a tcp packet.I have tested re-writing and without re-writing the checksum (as I said the packet length is not changed so the checksum won't change, i guess).I amn't dropping the packets. These are my iptables rules: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j QUEUE iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j QUEUE Wireshark shows the original had already arrived but this only reaches my sniffer program and not the actual client. So the client is unable to send the ack for that packet. The server keeps re-transmitting the packet with the same sequence number.

Comment: Perhaps my points weren't clear enough. Here i go again. Checksum will change if you have modified any thing in the packet. It doesn't matter if the length is same. You can select in wireshark options to validate the checksum. So you would be able to see. The second thing i already asked is, if you are not dropping the original packet, how is it is not reaching the destination? My expectation was that original does reach the destination and your new packet with the same sequence number and probably invalid checksum is being discarded. Please validate each of these scenarios.