# Fields in ip/tcp header required to be changed when data is modified in an IP packet

Tags: linux, network-programming, packet-sniffers, netfilter

This is an extension to my other question- [modifying ip packet using libipq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023945/modifying-ip-packet-using-libipq)
I have a linux bridge set up between a client and a server machine. I forward the tcp packets coming from the server to the client during I modify data in certain packets. I am calculating the new checksum on the packets that I modify. The packets that are unmodified get forwarded properly whereas the packets that I modify are not getting forwarded to the client. I am using the following statement to accept and forward the packet after I modify the packet:

```
ipq_set_verdict (h, m->packet_id, NF_ACCEPT, m->data_len, m->payload);
```

My iptable rule is"

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j QUEUE
```

Any help how I can overcome this?

Comment: In the other question, fayyazkl respond it to the same question. His questions were good: are you sure that the checksum is correct and did you dropped the original packet from TCP flow?

Comment: I think the checksum is correct. Wireshark also confirms this. Wireshark application on the client machine is seeing the packet in right format without any error. So the packet isn't being dropped.